# Kohana ORM has_many belongs_to

Tags: php, orm, kohana

Lets say I have 3 models, One, Two, and Three.

Model One has many Three, Model Two has many Three, Three belongs to One and Two.

Models:

```
class Model_One extends ORM {

protected $_primary_key = 'one_id';

protected $_has_many = array(
    'threes'=> array(
        'model' => 'three',                
        'through' => 'ones_threes',   
        'far_key' => 'three_id',       
        'foreign_key' => 'one_id'   
        ),
    );
}

class Model_Two extends ORM {

protected $_primary_key = 'two_id';

protected $_has_many = array(
    'threes'=> array(
        'model' => 'three',                
        'through' => 'twos_threes',   
        'far_key' => 'three_id',       
        'foreign_key' => 'two_id'   
        ),
    );
}

class Model_Three extends ORM {

protected $_primary_key = 'three_id';

protected $_belongs_to = array(
    'ones'=> array(
        'model' => 'one',                
        'through' => 'ones_threes',    
        'far_key' => 'one_id',       
        'foreign_key' => 'three_id'   
        ),

'twos'=> array(
        'model' => 'two',                
        'through' => 'twos_threes',    
        'far_key' => 'two_id',       
        'foreign_key' => 'three_id'   
        ),
);
}
```

I display One, Two, Three.

```
$getTwos=ORM::factory('two')->find_all(); 

foreach($getTwos as $getTwo)
{
   echo $getTwo->two_category_title;
   foreach($getTwo->three->find_all() as $getThree)
   {
       echo $getThree->three_title;
       echo $getThree->one->one_author; 
   }
}
```

Lets say I have author A and B and Title 1, Title 2, Title 3, and Title 4. A has Title 1, 2, 3, and B has Title 4.

Problem is echo $getThree->one->one_author; will echo A, B, NULL, NULL.

How can I echo the information correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect relation definitions in your model `Three`. It seems like `One` has and belongs to many `Threes` (HABTM or "has many through"), the same for `Two` model. Here is what you need:

```
class Model_Three extends ORM {

protected $_primary_key = 'three_id';

protected $_has_many = array(
    'ones'=> array(
        'model' => 'one',                
        'through' => 'ones_threes',    
        'far_key' => 'one_id',       
        'foreign_key' => 'three_id'   
        ),

    'twos'=> array(
        'model' => 'two',                
        'through' => 'twos_threes',    
        'far_key' => 'two_id',       
        'foreign_key' => 'three_id'   
        ),
    );
}
```

**PS**. `foreign_key` is optional, because you already define it in `$_primary_key` property.

**PPS**. Here is an example for a "Post belongs to only one User" relation:

```
class Model_User extends ORM {

   protected $_has_many = array(
      'posts' => array(),
   );
}

class Model_Post extends ORM {

   protected $_belongs_to = array(
      'author' => array(
          'model'       => 'user',
          // ignore if you have a `author_id` foreign key
          'foreign_key' => 'user_id', 
      ),
   );

   protected $_has_many = array(...);
}

// usage
$post = ORM::factory('post', 1);
echo $post->author->username;
$post->author = ORM::factory('user', 1);
$user = ORM::factory('user', 1);
foreach($user->posts->where('published', '=', 1)->find_all() as $posts) {
    echo $post->title;
}
```

Comment: What if One, Two, Three, were instead Users, Categories, Posts. Does the setup you present still make sense? I'm struggling to make sense with relations.

Comment: Have you read an official documentation? http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/relationships#hasmany-through

Comment: Sure have...many many times same with other's examples. I just don't know how to approach what I'm doing. I don't know how to call upon Users within Posts, when Users is not related to Categories and Posts can only have one user.